# How to determine number of genus from given equation of a surface?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, surfaces

In "[Topics in Differential Geometry](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/dgbook.pdf)" book of [Peter W. Michor](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/) page 15, he gives an example of a compact surface of genus $g$ as follows:

> Let $f(x) := x(x − 1)^2(x −
> 2)^2\cdots(x − (g − 1))^2(x − g)$. For small $r > 0$ the set $M:=\{(x, y, z) : (y^2 +
> f(x))^2 +z^2 = r^2\}$ describes a surface of genus $g$.

I tried to plot this example using MAPLE but I couldn't do it correctly (see [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20(y%5E2%2Bx*(x-1)%5E2*(x-2)%5E2*(x-3))%5E2%2Bz%5E2%20%3D%201,%20x%20%3D%20-3%20..%203,%20y%20%3D%20-2%20..%202,%20z%20%3D%20-3%20..%203) for similar plot for $g=3$). My question is:

> **Q1:** Is it possible to realize that this example is a surface of genus $g$ without plotting it?
>
> **Q2:** Is there a nice pictured $g$-genus surface equation something like connected sum of $g$ torus?

Comment: Q1: The height function should be Morse; then one can count the number of critical points of various index to find the Euler characteristic. Q2sure, look on the Wikipedia page for surface, the g=2 case, and generalize to Tori arranged in a line.

Comment: Thank you Mike Miller.  Do you mean this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus-two_surface? there is nothing there!!

Comment: There is a fantastic picture of a genus two surface. I am not sure what else you were looking for in Q2.

Comment: I think I stated my second question ambiguously!! my question is about algebraic equation of a g-genus surface.